# Maximum value of $\sin (x)\;\sin (2x)\;\sin (3x)$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

To prove : $\sin (x)\;\sin (2x)\;\sin (3x) \lt 9/16$

With some transformations i was able to prove the above result using calculus but I am not getting the way to solve it without the use of calculus

I've tried grouping $\sin(x)\;\sin(3x)$ and then using product to sum transformations.

Also I've tried to find the maximum value of sinxsin3x and then using the fact that sin2x is a fraction. Although I was able to prove that sinxsin3x is less than 9/16 but the minimum value was less than -9/16 and since sin2x can be negative so i could not draw any conclusion.

Comment: What about inserting spaces ?

Comment: It is not a minimum but a maximum (or sup) value.

Comment: Why did you undo my edit?  The thing is very hard to read with no spaces...I suggest you insert spaces.  If you look at the reformatted text in my edit you will see the syntax I used.

Comment: I ve edited the post keeping in mind the suggestions

Comment: @lulu I haven't undone your edit.I corrected some mistakes maybe during that all this happened.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a= \sin x ,b = \cos x$ and $a^2+b^2=1$,

Since $\sin 2x = 2 \sin x \cos x = 2 a b$

And $\sin 3x = \sin x (2\cos x+1)(2\cos x-1) = a (2b+1)(2b-1)$

Thus we have $\sin x \sin 2x \sin 3x = 8a^3 b^3 -2a^3 b$

Substitute instead of $b = +\sqrt{1-a^2}$ and once $b=-\sqrt{1-a^2}$

Solving the inequality $8a^3 b^3 -2a^3 b < \frac{9}{16}$ will be easy from here.

Answer (score -1):

Let $\cos^2x=t$.

Thus, we need to prove that
$$2\sin^3x\cos{x}(3-4\sin^2x)<\frac{9}{16}$$ or
$$\sin^3x\cos{x}(4\cos^2x-1)<\frac{9}{32},$$
which is obviously true for
$$\sin^3x\cos{x}(4\cos^2x-1)\leq0.$$

Now, let $\sin^3x\cos{x}(4\cos^2x-1)>0$.

Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$t(1-t)^3(4t-1)^2<\frac{81}{1024}.$$
1. Let $\frac{1}{4}<t<1.$

Thus, we need to prove that $f(t)<\ln\frac{81}{1024},$ where
$$f(t)=\ln{t}+3\ln(1-t)+2\ln(4t-1).$$

Indeed, $$f'(t)=\frac{1}{t}-\frac{3}{1-t}+\frac{8}{4t-1}=-\frac{24t^2-16t+1}{(1-t)t(4t-1)},$$
which gives $t_{max}=\frac{4+\sqrt{10}}{12}$ and since $f\left(\frac{4+\sqrt{10}}{12}\right)<\ln\frac{81}{1024},$ we are done in this case;

2. $0<t<\frac{1}{4}$.

The work in this case is the same: $g(t)=\ln{t}+3\ln(1-t)+2\ln(1-4t)$...